# Quickly view the total sum of execution cost in execution plan

Tags: sql-server

I have a large execution plan. Is there a way to quickly view the total sum of IO cost, CPU cost, etc. for the full plan without manually calculating each node?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but many folks praise [This Free Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) as being an easier way to view some key plan metrics. I do not work for them and nor am I plugging them, but maybe it has a feature.

Comment: Hover on the left top most iterator and it will show you the total sum of all costs.

Answer (score 0):

[SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) is a great tool for analysing SQL Server execution plans. I don't work for them, I use this tool very often.

It can show the costs of individual operator or cumulative costs.

[image: subtree cost]